# Deliver static content on CDN directly using reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, domain, reverse-proxy, cdn

I have a CDN which hosts static content (possibly Github pages or CloudFlare, depending on answers). Our server generates dynamically JSON resources. I would like all content to be accessible under the same domain name.

i.e.:

```
Client <========> proxy <========>server
   ^                |
   |                ⌄
   =============== CDN
```

The problem is that the CDN can't act as a reverse proxy and that if I setup a reverse proxy on the server, all data will be forwarded through it, thus making the delivery time longer and possibly using memory and processing power on the server.

How to keep all data under one domain name but deliver CDN content directly to end users?

Comment: Depends what CDN you're using. CloudFlare for example works as a pass-through and everything is on the same domain. You haven't told us enough for us to help you. Question is unclear.

Comment: Every CDN can handle this. You just need to respond with the right cache control headers so that the dynamic responses aren't cached.

Comment: @Tim Github Pages or CloudFlare, not decided yet. Edited question